# How to CFDUMP the "Body" of an HTTP POST

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfhttp

Here's my question of the day.  Let's say I have this on one page:

**start.cfm**

```
<cfset body = { "stuff": [ 1,2,3,4,5 ] }>

<cfhttp url="end.cfm" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(body)#">
</cfhttp>
```

I can't figure out what end.cfm needs to have to output what's in the body.  I've tried to cfdump everything from variables to form to cgi but I can't get to it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such a dumb question that I was able to answer it with some additional Googling.

```
 <cfdump var="#GetHttpRequestData()#">
```

Comment: It is a good question. I was unfamiliar with this function. I now see how it can be useful

Comment: Agreed. If you are used dealing with forms and fields, you never think about how to retrieve a body *only*

Comment: You guys are too kind. I hate it when the answer is literally two Google clicks away!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the "start and end page to see what's in the request" solution is to use Hyper:

https://www.forgebox.io/view/hyper

It wraps cfhttp but does so in a manner that lets you re-use elements of your request that are shared with other calls to the same endpoints. It's especially useful when paired with Wirebox and Coldbox but these are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this...first time seeing Forgebox. CommandBox really has breathed new life into CFML, hasn't it? Great to see my favorite language receiving a second wind. :-)